# Geometry node: point instance from nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to do a Geometry node (I'm using Blender 2.93) that distributes some cones on the surface of a shape. For now, I need to create a new shape just for the cone, and then use `Point Instance` with this object:

[image]

However, I'd much prefer to directly give the instance object from the Geometry node directly (i.e. without using another object) to make sure everything self contained, via something like:

[image]

(which does not work for now, I guess the type Geometry is not compatible with Object)

Is it possible? If not, what is the goal of having this orange "Object" input?

Comment: This feature is planned for the next version (hopefully)

Comment: See https://developer.blender.org/T89657

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the link to the issue!

Answer (score 2):

It is for the object which you want to instance. If you e.g. create a cone with SHIFT-A - Mesh - Cone you can then select your cone there.

Here an example how it could be used:

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks. But does that mean that there is no way to do what I want to do, i.e. plug directly a "cone" obtained via "Mesh primitive" as input of the point instance object?

Comment: AFAIK not in the moment. Maybe in future versions....